# What's the smallest amount of memory that can be allocated to GPU?

Tags: raspbian, memory, gpu, memory-split

According to http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Memory , the minimum that can be specified in /boot/config.txt is 16MB. Is there a way to shut off video completely and allocate nothing?

I'm asking about Raspbian but would be curious to know if another Pi OS allows less or fully disabling video.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum is 16 MB.

The GPU actually handles a lot of other things, including RAM, booting, firing up the ARM, etc. Not just video. We should all give it some respect.

Comment: 16 MB ought to be enough for any GPU.